# Safari anchor download

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, safari

On the site I'm working on we have some download links for images. We tested on an older macbook running safari 5 and that worked perfectly. However when we updated the OS, safari went to version 8 and now when you click the download link it renames every file "download-#" and changes the extension from JPEG to a TextEdit document.  Chrome and Firefox on the same laptop don't do this, only happens in Safari.

If you "Save Image to "Downloads" or "Save Image As..." the filename and extension remain unchanged.

Is there a way to force it to keep the original filename and extension, when using the download links?